# Emacs + tramp + plink

Tags: emacs, ssh, amazon-ec2, tramp, plink

I'm trying to get emacs tramp running under Windows XP to work over putty plink on an Amazon EC2 instance.  The documentation for doing this is sparse. I can find partial documentation, but none that addresses all the steps required to get this working.

Can anyone provide a walk through, or a pointer to a walk through?

Comment: It might help to explain what you have tried already, and what sort of problems you are having when following the documentation you mentioned. E.g. is there something specific about EC2 that is significantly different from other environments?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
(add-to-list 'load-path
 (expand-file-name "C:/tools/emacsw32/emacs/lisp/tramp/lisp"))
(require 'tramp)
;(setq tramp-chunksize "500")
(setq tramp-default-method "plink")
```

from my dot-emacs file.  If I find more notes, I shall add them here.

Comment: One thing this doesn't address is using a keyfile.

Answer (score 5):

I'll assume you have a GNU/Linux server you want to access, a username and a .ppk file. Also, Emacs 24.4+.

First set up server in PuTTY Configuration

1. In section Session, specify Host Name, for example `username@server`.
2. Go to section Connection > SSH > Auth and Browse for your "Private key file for authentication".
3. Back to section Session, name your Saved Sessions, for example `putty-test`, and click Save button.
4. Check your connection by clicking the Open button. If it works, you can close these now.

Next, head to your Emacs.

1. Make sure Emacs knows where your `plink.exe` is. One way is to just inform Emacs directly in your `.emacs`, for instance I have at the moment, 
   `(setenv "PATH" (concat "c:/Users/Brady/Documents/putty/;" (getenv "PATH")))`
2. Simply type `C-x C-f //plink:putty-test:/ RET`. Wait a moment while it connects, and window will open to `dired` buffer on the remote `~/` directory.

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me on :

- Windows 10
- Emacs found at https://sourceforge.net/projects/emacsbinw64/files/release/.
- cygwin64
- Putty.
- https://github.com/d5884/fakecygpty

The changes from the original `tramp-sh.el` is

- for cygwin, use fakecygpty with ssh and change the prompt to `##`
- for plink, remove `-ssh` option

I have also renamed these method with `w` to differentiate it.

```
(when (string-equal system-type "windows-nt")
  (add-to-list 'tramp-methods
               `("sshw"
                 (tramp-login-program        "fakecygpty ssh")
                 ;; ("%h") must be a single element, see `tramp-compute-multi-hops'.
                 (tramp-login-args           (("-l" "%u" "-o \"StrictHostKeyChecking=no\"") ("-P" "%p") ("-t")
                                              ("%h") ("\"")
                                              (,(format
                                                 "env 'TERM=%s' 'PROMPT_COMMAND=' 'PS1=%s'"
                                                 tramp-terminal-type
                                                 "##"))
                                              ("/bin/sh") ("\"")))
                 (tramp-remote-shell         "/bin/sh")
                 (tramp-remote-shell-login   ("-l"))
                 (tramp-remote-shell-args    ("-c"))
                 (tramp-default-port         22))
               )

  (add-to-list 'tramp-methods
               `("plinkw"
                 (tramp-login-program        "plink")
                 ;; ("%h") must be a single element, see `tramp-compute-multi-hops'.
                 (tramp-login-args           (("-l" "%u") ("-P" "%p") ("-t")
                                              ("%h") ("\"")
                                              (,(format
                                                 "env 'TERM=%s' 'PROMPT_COMMAND=' 'PS1=%s'"
                                                 tramp-terminal-type
                                                 "$"))
                                              ("/bin/sh") ("\"")))
                 (tramp-remote-shell         "/bin/sh")
                 (tramp-remote-shell-login   ("-l"))
                 (tramp-remote-shell-args    ("-c"))
                 (tramp-default-port         22))
               )
  )
```