# Accessing local emacs from PuTTY

Tags: emacs, putty

My school (UCSB) has us use PuTTY to remotely access our CS account that's ran on the school's server. Whenever I attempt to use the school's emacs via PuTTY, it's extremely tedious because it's all in text user interface. I do have an option to use Xming to access the GUI Emacs, but that's incredibly slow since it still relies on the server's emacs. So now I'm fed up of relying on using WinSCP as a text-editor (I know it isn't suppose to be a text-editor) on my laptop, and want to use emacs without the terrible interface or speed. I finally went to the GNU website to download a local copy of emacs on my laptop. However I can't do anything with it unless I constantly transfer my files from the school's server to my laptop for editing, and vice-versa for compiling, which can be very tedious.

So, is there a way I can use PuTTY to access the files on my school's account and then have them opened using my local emacs? Or is there any other ideas or tools to help me with my situation?

Comment: If you were on Linux you could use the FISH protocol, but on Windows you're out of luck, I'm afraid…

Comment: You can configure TRAMP (Emacs library to access files on other hosts through e.g. SSH) to use PuTTY. I've never done it myself, but [this](http://dietbuddha.blogspot.co.uk/2012/11/configing-emacs-tramp-with-putty.html) came up in a quick Google search.

Comment: Oh, and [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1095172/emacs-tramp-plink?rq=1) might be useful.

Answer (score 2):

TRAMP would be the way to go. In order for TRAMP to use PuTTY by default do this

```
 (setq tramp-default-method "plinkx")
```

After that you can access the files or use `dired` on your remote host by using paths like

```
 /name_of_Putty_session:/path/on/remote/host
```

Comment: Just enter path like that when you need to open a file on a remote host (after C-x C-f) or a directory (after C-x d)